# Crossfilter in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, crossfilter

Does anyone know whether [Crossfilter](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) is likely to work in IE8?

I don't have a copy of Windows available to check it out. I need to support IE8 in my finished app, but don't know whether even starting with Crossfilter is a no-no.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, if you don't have a copy of physical Windows available, you should at least have a virtual machine. Really expect anything to break in IE if you don't test it. An alternative is to have IE run on your closest Linux box via Wine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses HTML5 features, so I'm guessing, no :)

See also: http://caniuse.com/#feat=typedarrays

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I'm not sure that this works.  I'm getting some weird intermittent bugs and I think this may be the cause.  I haven't isolated it yet but I wanted to give a heads up before someone comes across this and tries it.

There's [a fork on github](https://github.com/zackham/crossfilter/tree/ie8compatible) that uses underscore shims.  Naturally you'll also need to include [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).

If you're using another library like Mootools or whatever you can just find/replace .forEach, .isArray, .map, and .indexOf with your library's equivalent functions.  It's only a few lines.